# Best way to retrieve tracking event from marketing cloud ? [Python]

Tags: marketing-cloud, python

Using FUELSDK library, We recently implemented our sync pipeline to sync data from our side into Salesforce marketing cloud.

Now, the next thing that we would like to do is to fetch all tracking events (open, click, sent, delivered, etc.,) from the marketing cloud into our system. Based on the soap api document, it looks like we have to access separate endpoints to fetch information related to each tracking event. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/click-tracking.htm

Is there an easy to retrieve all this information using one endpoint rather than hitting five different endpoints?

Thanks,
Sahil

Comment: Ping here.. I would appreciate your response for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In its current implementation, that will not be possible as all the events are written as seperate classed.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/blob/master/FuelSDK/objects.py

You could submit a pull request that uses this soap envelope:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api.htm

or... write a helper function to aggregate calls from all the different classes.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using separate classes for now. But its good to know, that it is a SDK limitation.